# Using AutoMapper when having a LINQ statement with multiple .Include

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

So I am new to using AutoMapper and have been able to get basic mapping of items no problem with using LINQ statements that do not use the .Include("blah"), however when I have a statement for example like this;

```
var courses = dc.Courses.Include("Students")
                        .Include("CourseTimes")
                        .OrderBy(n=>n.CourseSemester.courseStart);
```

AutoMapper doesnt seem to pull any of the information from ("Students") or ("CourseTimes"). My objects are posted below and to give a quick breakdown, Courses contain a List of Students(I need Students so I can count the number of people in each course), Courses also contain a List of CourseTimes(so I can display the times of each class for the given course). Here is my ViewModel that I am using.

```
public class UserIndexCourseList
{
    [Key]
    public int courseId { get; set; }
    public string courseCode { get; set; }

    public string courseName { get; set; }

    // this simply stored a count when I did Students.Count without using AutoMapper
    public int size { get; set; } 

    public string room { get; set; }

    public List<CourseTime> courseTimeSlot { get; set; }

}
```

Here are some of the AutoMapper statements I tried to used but had no luck with it working.

```
//to the viewmodel
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Course, ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.CourseTime, ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Student, ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList>();

//from the viewmodel
        Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList, Models.Course>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList, Models.CourseTime>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList, Models.Student>();
```

So essentially how can I create a Map which will also pull all of that information so I can use it with my ViewModel that was posted above ? I have tried numerous options but no luck.

I apologize for a similar post I made ahead of time but I don't think I explained myself well enough the first time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention automapper maps properties with same names, so in your case you can do this:

```
public class UserIndexCourseList
{
    ...
    //rename field so it has same name as reference
    public List<CourseTime> CourseTimes{ get; set; }  
}
```

or you can rename reference in EF so it's name is courseTimeslot.

Another solution if you don't want to rename your property is to add options to map, for example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Course, ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList>()
.ForMember(d => d.courseTimeSlot,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CourseTime));
```

Edit: also they have great documentation, your case is described here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection

"Because the names of the destination properties do not exactly match up to the source property (CalendarEvent.Date would need to be CalendarEventForm.EventDate), we need to specify custom member mappings in our type map configuration..."

Comment: AMAZING ! Thank you very much for this, I applied the name changes to my solution and it resolved the issue. I have one final question. I used this line here;

    `Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Course, ViewModels.UserIndexCourseList>().ForMember(d=>d.size, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Students.Count));`

Is this a perfectly valid way for doing a count like this ? It does work for me and I was able to get an accuarte count of the Students in each class but I was wondering if there was a better way or this is acceptable?

Comment: Acceptable, but personaly I would just do this `public int size { get; {return Students.Count;} }` if you have them as list in your class, if not, you don't need to retrieve them along with course, rather just count them (better performance).